# 8051 - I2C BitBang

Tags: i2c, 8051

Im using I2C bitbang and Im facing an issue. I think I need a delay between SCL and SDA lines. Im not sure how much the delay needs to be.
Can someone check my I2C code to see if everything checks out? I want to make sure its not a software mistake.

```
#include <at89c51ic2.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SDA P0_0
#define SCL P0_1

void I2CInit(){
    SDA = 1;
    SCL = 1;
}
void I2CStart(){
    SCL = 1;
    I2CDelay();
    SDA = 0;
    I2CDelay();
    SCL = 0;
    I2CDelay();
}
void I2CRestart(){
    SDA = 1;
    SCL = 1;
    SDA = 0;
    SCL = 0;
}
void I2CStop(){
    SDA = 0;
    I2CDelay();
    SCL = 1;
    I2CDelay();
    SDA = 1;
    I2CDelay();
}
void I2CAck(){
    I2CDelay();
    SDA = 0;
    I2CDelay();
    SCL = 1;
    I2CDelay();
    SCL = 0;
    I2CDelay();
    SDA = 1;
    I2CDelay();
}
void I2CNak(){
    SDA = 1;
    SCL = 1;
    SCL = 0;
    SDA = 1;
} 
void I2CSend(unsigned char Data){
    unsigned char i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        if ((Data & 0x80) == 0)
            SDA = 0;
        else
            SDA = 1;
        SCL = 1;
        I2CDelay();
        SCL = 0;
        I2CDelay();
        Data <<= 1;
    }
    SDA = 1; 
    I2CDelay();
    SCL = 1;
    I2CDelay();
    if (SDA)
        SCL = 0;
    I2CDelay();
    SDA = 1;
    SCL = 1;
    }

char I2CRead(unsigned char lastone){ // last one == 1 for last byte; 0 for any other byte
    char i, Data=0;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        SCL = 1;
        I2CDelay();
        if(SDA) Data |=1;
        if(i<7) Data<<=1;
        SCL = 0;
        I2CDelay();
}
    SDA = lastone;
    SCL = 1;
    I2CDelay();
    SCL = 0;
    SDA = 1;
    SCL = 1;
    I2CDelay();
    return Data;
}

void I2CSendAddr(unsigned char addr, unsigned char rd){
    I2CStart();
    I2CSend(addr+rd);
}
void I2CDelay(){
    unsigned int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 4000; i++);
    return;
}
```

Comment: You will need to check with an oscilloscope yourself. I know some compilers which would optimize the delay away completely. We also don't know how "loaded" your I²C bus is.

Comment: Calculate - DelayTime = (CPU frequency / Max permissible i2c frequency your peripheral). considering your i2c bus is not multi master & is not heavily loaded. _nop_ instruction time = 1 machine cycle time period. _CPU frequency = Crystal frequency/12_. Generally, delay function with 2 nop does it for a 12MHz Crystal freq.